# How do magnetorquers work?

Tags: artificial-satellite, physics

I'm working on a project that involves magnetorquers, and as someone with only a basic understanding of physics (and even more basic understanding of electromagnetism), I have absolutely no idea how these things do what they do. As far as I've been able to suss out, it has something to do with an induced current causing an electromagnetic field and that somehow translates to momentum? Can someone help please?

Comment: The somehow translates to momentum is from the induced magnetic field interacting with the magnetic field of the Earth. Think of the magnetorquers as magnets, if you put them near another magnet (The Earths magnetic field) then there will be a force between them!